# Selenium IDE Version 3.17.0 how to catch new window handle

Tags: selenium, window, selenium-ide, handle

I'm **looking for a way to open a new window and have control over it** so i can continue testing it. The select window command requires the handle of the new window but **I have not yet found how to retrieve this handle**. Please do not answer me if you have not personally tried the solution you want to propose with version 3.17.0 or later of Selenium IDE.
I spent many hours looking for a solution that works with the Selenium IDE in version 3.17.0 or higher. **I am not looking for a solution that makes use of java code or other language, i am looking for a solution that can be used in the Selenium IDE plugin**, especially for the Firefox browser. The web is full of examples and tutorials but none working with version 3.17.0 o superior.
This is an example (not working because win_ser_1 is not good) of what i'm trying to achieve: [image]
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

For the example you give I don't have an exact answer since you open a new window with JS.
But if you for instance have link that opens a new window there is options in SeleniumIDE to store the new window handle.
I'll show an example. I have a button that triggers a new window to pop up.
Here is how to store the handle:

[image: store window handle]

Be sure to check the checkbox:

[image: name window handle]

here is how I use it in the script:

[image: use window handle]

Comment: How to close it and go back to the previous window?